# How to convert array object to object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Convert an array object to separate separate object without object key. I like to

```
const arr = [ 
{ public_id: 'apple', secure_url: 'one' },
{ public_id: 'banana', secure_url: 'two' },
{ public_id: 'orange', secure_url: 'three' }
];
```

And i need to convert to

```
{ public_id: 'apple', secure_url: 'one' },
{ public_id: 'banana', secure_url: 'two' },
{ public_id: 'orange', secure_url: 'three' }
```

Comment: What's the difference between those two things supposed to be?

Comment: Every object will be stored in different variables. they cant be stored in single variable as you have mentioend

Comment: `separate object without object key` there is no such data structure.  An array is closest, like you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructuring to extract the array entries into individual variables:

```js
const arr = [
{ public_id: 'apple', secure_url: 'one' },
{ public_id: 'banana', secure_url: 'two' },
{ public_id: 'orange', secure_url: 'three' }
]

let [a,b,c] = arr

console.log(a)
console.log(b)
console.log(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second one is not a valid data structure.

You could however convert it to something like this:

```
{
0: { public_id: 'apple', secure_url: 'one' },
1: { public_id: 'banana', secure_url: 'two' },
2: { public_id: 'orange', secure_url: 'three' },
}
```

like this:

```
const obj = {}
arr.forEach((item, i) => {
  obj[i] = item
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not get what you meant by saying seperate object without object key.
It is comletely fine to store and reach objects in/from array, but if what you want is to iterate through objects in array then you can use built-in `map()` or `forEach()` functions.